# Bootstrap: nav items font color doesn't change according to theme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

According to the [basic bootstrap documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#color-schemes) using .navbar-inverse should change the font color of the items to white:

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-inverse bg-primary">
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
 <a class="nav-item" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
 <a class="nav-item" href="#">Link</a>
 <a class="nav-item" href="#">Disabled</a>
</nav>
```

However, the items in my navbar have a font color identical to the background.

I can override this using

```
.navbar a {
  color:white;
}
```

But I'd rather use bootstrap out of the box, and this is such a basic feature that I shouldn't have to override it?

Comment: Try https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ and change @navbar-default-link-color . Then download css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your comments. I actually copied and pasted my own code from this question back to codepen.io and now it works. Maybe an issue with codepen or my browser...

Found out what was the actual problem, it says right in the first sentence on the bootstrap doc:

> Navbars require a wrapping `.navbar` with `.navbar-toggleable-*` for
>   responsive collapsing and color scheme classes.

I didn't use `.navbar-toggleable-*`

Comment: Hi @Danieal Speich, happy to hear you solved the issue. Please make sure you mark an answer as correct one so people will see it has a correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is template using bootstrap 4:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I think what you are doing wrong might be the fact that you are not using `<ul>` > `<li>` html tags to put the links inside. Try to wrap them with appropriate html tags and see if the theme will be changed accordingly.

Here you have a working fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/obc4x20g/)